# Jquery mobile show chart in child a page

Tags: jquery-mobile, cordova, charts

I want to display rgraph bar chart on second page of my multipage Jquery Mobile App. Here is the structure of my code

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
  <head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-   1.4.2.min.css">
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.js">    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="rgraph/libraries/RGraph.common.core.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="rgraph/libraries/RGraph.bar.js"></script>
    <script src="rgraph/libraries/RGraph.gauge.js"></script> 
    <script src="rgraph/libraries/RGraph.cornergauge.js"></script>
    <script src="rgraph/libraries/RGraph.common.dynamic.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>

  <div data-role="page" id="pageone">
  <div data-role="header">
    <h1>Welcome To My Homepage</h1>
  </div>

  <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
  <p>Welcome! If you click on the link below, it will take you to Page Two.</p>
  <a href="#pagetwo">Go to Page Two</a>
  </div>

 <div data-role="footer">
  <h1>Footer Text</h1>
</div>
</div> 

  <div data-role="page" id="pagetwo">
  <div data-role="header">
    <h1>Welcome To My Homepage</h1>
   </div>

  <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
   // My chart should come here

  <canvas id="cvs" width="500" height="250">[No canvas support]</canvas>

   <script>
    $(document).ready(function ()
    {
        var data = [[4,5,3],[4,8,6],[4,2,4],[4,2,3],[1,2,3],[8,8,4],[4,8,6]];

        var bar = new RGraph.Bar('cvs', data)
            .set('labels', ['Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday','Thursday','Friday','Saturday','Sunday'])
            .set('labels.above', true)
            .set('colors', ['red','yellow', 'pink'])
            .set('bevel', !RGraph.ISOLD)
            .set('grouping', 'stacked')
            .set('strokestyle', 'rgba(0,0,0,0)')
            .draw();
    })
</script>


 <a href="#pageone">Go to Page One</a>
 </div>

<div data-role="footer">
 <h1>Footer Text</h1>
 </div>
 </div> 

 </body>
 </html>
```

But chart is showing on the first page (main page).Is Jquery mobile Document.ready function is working for child pages?if not what should i change to make this working..please help

Comment: your code is working fine, i have tried your code and the char is getting on second page as you wanted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For jQuery Mobile, don't use `$(document).ready(function ()...`. Instead use the provided page and/or pagecontainer events.  For your example you could put the script at the bottom of the html (outside all page markup) and inside a `pagecreate` event for pagetwo:

```
$(document).on("pagecreate", "#pagetwo", function(){

        var data = [[4,5,3],[4,8,6],[4,2,4],[4,2,3],[1,2,3],[8,8,4],[4,8,6]];

        var bar = new RGraph.Bar('cvs', data)
            .set('labels', ['Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday','Thursday','Friday','Saturday','Sunday'])
            .set('labels.above', true)
            .set('colors', ['red','yellow', 'pink'])
            .set('bevel', !RGraph.ISOLD)
            .set('grouping', 'stacked')
            .set('strokestyle', 'rgba(0,0,0,0)')
            .draw();

});
```

> Here is a working **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/3M2yS/)**